# Cant take a screenshot to a map with polylines in it

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am making an app that tracks the path a the user and draws a polyline on the path. My problem is when the user finishes his track and presses stop the map zooms out to contain the whole polyline but it doesn't take a screenshot (When i debug, it jumps the code of the screenshot and doesn't execute it).

My question is how to take a screenshot to the map that contains the whole polyline

**My code**

```
 stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                LatLngBounds.Builder builder= new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                latLngs = polylineOptions.getPoints();
                for(LatLng latLng : latLngs){
                    builder.include(latLng);
                }
                LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                int padding = 100;
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,padding);
                mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                final Intent[] intent = new Intent[1];
                intent[0] = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Results_Activity.class);

                mMap.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {

                                intent[0].putExtra("image",bitmap);


                            }
                        });

                startActivity(intent[0]);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling startActivity(intent[0]); before mMap.snapshot has a chance to finish in the callback. Try just moving startActivity(intent[0]); directly after intent[0].putExtra("image",bitmap);

Answer (score 0):

I managed to take a screenshot and send it to the second activity by using this code

**Code in First Activity**

```
stopButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {


                LatLngBounds.Builder builder= new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

                if(polylineOptions.getPoints()!= null){
                    latLngs = polylineOptions.getPoints();
                    for(LatLng latLng : latLngs){
                        builder.include(latLng);
                    }
                    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                    int padding = 100;
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,padding);
                    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                }

                intent[0] = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Results_Activity.class);

                final SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                        Bitmap image = snapshot;
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                        intent[0].putExtra("picture", byteArray);
                        startActivity(intent[0]);
                    }
                };

                mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapLoaded() {
                        mMap.snapshot(callback);

                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        });
```

**Code in Second Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results_);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        mapPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.TrackimageView);
        mapPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
```